# Expected behavior of an ApplicationScoped bean observing start/stop and mocking

Tags: quarkus

I have an application scoped bean observing start:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class SomeBean {
  protected void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {
    System.out.println("I'm here");
  }
}
```

I can of course see this hit the start method when the application starts.

In my @QuarkusTests, I don't actually need/want the start to be hit.

If I use @InjectMock SomeBean, or create a @Mock replacement that overrides the start, I still see the original onStart being called.

My workaround has been to switch to postconstruct/predestroy with an explicit usage of the bean to trigger the postconstruct.  I just wanted to see if what I'm observing is expected behavior.

Comment: Hello, what version of Quarkus do you use? It should behave as you expect in Quarkus 1.7+. See also https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/11122

Comment: I see this on Quarkus version 1.11.0.Final

Comment: Converted to an issue https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/15083